# Flexbox Wrap Not Working On 4 Of My Images

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

Hello Im not sure why but for some reason flexbox is not working.
I have 4 images on one section. I added flexbox wrap on the container and I also assigned flex 1
on the children images but for some reason flexbox is not working.

If anyone could help and let me know what I am doing wrong I would really appreciate it.

https://codepen.io/rubenjr005/pen/rNexOZp?editors=0100

HTML CODE

```
  <div id="capabilities" class="bg-dark-02 py-2 angle-top-bottom-right">
    <div class="capabilities-title">
      <h4 class="section-title text-center">CAPABILITIES</h4>
      <h3 class="lead text-center">I DO THINGS LIKE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="capabilities-container">
      <div class="category">
        <div class="content">
          <img src="img/graphic-design-icon_03.png" alt="Graphic Design" />
          <div class="text-animation">
            <h3 class="text-center">GRAPHIC DESIGN</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="category">
        <div class="content">
          <img src="img/Web-Design-icon_01.jpg" alt="Web Design" />
          <div class="text-animation">
            <h3 class="text-center">Web Design</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="category">
        <div class="content">
          <img src="img/web-development-01.png" alt="web Development" />
          <div class="text-animation">
            <h3 class="text-center">Web Development</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="category category4">
        <div class="content">
          <img src="img/email-development.png" alt="Email Development" />
          <div class="text-animation">
            <h3 class="text-center">Email Development</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

SCSS

```
#capabilities {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 4.5rem;

  .capabilities-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    // min-width: 20%;

    .category {
      display: flex;
      // flex-direction: column;
      flex: 1;
      padding: 1rem;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      min-width: 10rem;
      // width: 10rem;

      .content {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;

        img {
          position: absolute;
          top: 30%;
          height: 12rem;
          width: auto;
          display: block;
          // margin: auto;
          margin-bottom: 4rem;
          opacity: 0.4;
          transition: 0.75s;
          // padding-bottom: 4rem;
        }
        .text-animation {
          // position: absolute;
          text-align: center;
          padding-top: 15rem;
          transition-duration: 0.75s;
          text-align: center;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          // background: red;
          // margin: auto;

          h3 {
            color: white;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            // margin: auto;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    .category:hover .content img {
      opacity: 1;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      // padding-bottom: 0rem;
      // padding-bottom: 0rem;
    }

    .category:hover .content .text-animation {
      // opacity: 1.0;
      padding-top: 10rem;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are your images on `position: absolute` when you want to manage them with flexbox? Removing that, changing to `width: 100%` and using `max-height` instead of `height` seems to produce what you want (I believe). If not please add more detail to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get rid of **absolute** positioning on your **img** and you'll have to use **media queries**.

Starting from there, you'll see the `flex-wrap: wrap` working.

Here is a fork : https://codepen.io/hisato/pen/vYGLLNY?editors=0100

Also, if I may add, as a general advice avoid to transition `margin/padding/top/left` etc. You should always look for a way to transition the `transform` property, it will have the best performance.

Comment: Do a fork of OP's pen to better illustrate your solution

Comment: Thank god for stack overflow. This would have taken me forever to figure this out.

Comment: Thank you! Your Code Worked. Also I noticed you said I should get rid of padding-bottom for transition but after I got rid of padding bottom the text is right underneath the image. How do I adjust how far away the text is before the transition starts wihtout using padding?

Comment: Did you reuse the whole scss of my fork ? I changed some other things. If you want me to check your updated pen, please post it in these comments.